# Testing Datawarehouse to see what see what issues might have occurred after nightly jobs have run

Tags: sql-server, testing

I want to be able test all tables in the Data warehouse to see what has changed after nightly jobs have run. I am using the query below to see what tables have no rows however i'd like to expand the testing to see other things such as what fields have null values after the job has run. does anyone do similar testing and have a script that they use for this or any other things I should test for?

```
select
    t.name table_name,
    s.name schema_name,
    sum(p.rows) total_rows
from
    sys.tables t
    join sys.schemas s on (t.schema_id = s.schema_id)
    join sys.partitions p on (t.object_id = p.object_id)
where p.index_id in (0,1)
group by t.name,s.name
having sum(p.rows) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've written the following stored proc that checks all tables in my DWH to see what columns are null. similarly the same can be done for checking what numeric columns are zero.

```
alter PROCEDURE EMPTYSEARCH  


@WHICHTABLE VARCHAR(50)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @SQL      nVARCHAR(max),
@TABLENAME        VARCHAR(max) ,
@COLUMNNAME       VARCHAR(max)

CREATE TABLE #RESULTS(TBLNAME VARCHAR(60),COLNAME VARCHAR(60),SQL VARCHAR(600))
SELECT 
  SYSOBJECTS.NAME AS TBLNAME,
  SYSCOLUMNS.NAME AS COLNAME,
  TYPE_NAME(SYSCOLUMNS.XTYPE) AS DATATYPE
  INTO #FKFINDER
    FROM SYSOBJECTS
      INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS ON SYSOBJECTS.ID=SYSCOLUMNS.ID
    WHERE SYSOBJECTS.XTYPE='U'
   AND SYSOBJECTS.NAME = @WHICHTABLE
    AND TYPE_NAME(SYSCOLUMNS.XTYPE) IN ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','NCHAR')
    ORDER BY TBLNAME,COLNAME

DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TBLNAME,COLNAME FROM #FKFINDER ORDER BY TBLNAME,COLNAME
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @TABLENAME,@COLUMNNAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = '
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [' + @TABLENAME + '] WHERE (select count(*) from [' + @TABLENAME + '] where [' +  @COLUMNNAME + '] is null) = (select count(*) from [' + @TABLENAME + '] ))
        INSERT INTO #RESULTS(TBLNAME,COLNAME,SQL) VALUES(''' + @TABLENAME + ''',''' +  @COLUMNNAME + ''','' 
        SELECT * FROM  [' + @TABLENAME + ']  WHERE (select count(*) from [' + @TABLENAME + '] where [' +  @COLUMNNAME + '] is null) = (select count(*) from [' + @TABLENAME + '] '') ;'
        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC (@SQL)
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @TABLENAME,@COLUMNNAME
    END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1

SELECT * FROM #RESULTS
```